# What is the meaning of these American football trash talk expressions?

Tags: american-football, nfl

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsWQuuFsnG4) humorously lists possible trash-talking in the NFL. What is the joke of the following "insults"?

> #5 Your receivers can't run a clean route on a Hail Mary.

What is a clean route and why is it / isn't it difficult to run during a Hail Mary pass?

> #8 Your running back is ridiculous. He has no game. He has mud on his jersey even though his games are being played in a dome.

Why wouldn't domed playing areas not be muddy, and why is it a particularly good insult that a running back has mud on his jersey?

> #9 The ref threw the flag *on* your quarterback for pass interference.

I don't get this joke at all - isn't pass interference only applicable to the defensive team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all cases, there is a more or less direct implication that the player(s) lack the skill or integrity to deserve a place in the game.

## 5

A clean route is a path which takes the runner away from potential tacklers and into space where the thrown ball can be received.

Since a Hail Mary play involves almost all offensive players being runners, this would imply the offensive players are either unable to run into such space or actively run into defensive players.

## 8

"In a dome" implies an indoor field, which almost always use artificial turf due to the difficulty of maintaining real grass. Artificial turf does not require dirt, does not become more than damp, and therefore should never be muddy.

"Have/Got game" is a term describing general prowess in more than just pure playing skill, but in the meta aspects of the sport.

This suggests the player added mud to their jersey, attempting to appear committed to the game (since the mud would come from being tackled or blocked, evidence of being active in play) but ironically forgetting there should be no mud regardless.

## 9

A flag thrown "on" a player implies the player had committed a foul which resulted in a flag being thrown by a referee or other official such as an illegitimate interference with a pass, thereby preventing a good offensive play.

Since the quarterback is the one **making** the pass, this suggests they are somehow interfering with their own team's intent, further implying a lack of throwing skill or perhaps even sabotage and cheating of some kind.

Comment: There is offensive pass interference when the receiver interferes with the defenders ability to catch the pass.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure I understand: It's easy to run for at a Hail Mary play because there are more offensive runners than there would be at other plays?

Comment: Normally there are fewer players attempting to run because they're protecting the QB or another receiver: safe but small gains, maybe a lucky large one. The HM goes for the low chance of an extreme gain because there isn't time for building up a set of the safe rebuts smaller plays, so it's more "every mam for himself and hope one gets there".